# Best way to color only the faces that are not debossed

Tags: modeling, shaders, faces

I apologize if this is a simple question but for the life of me I cannot figure the best way to color this "warning label" I am working with a .wrl file so I just have reference to work with no materials. I know I could UV map it but don't have the exact sticker or label either. I figured there might be a way to select all of the faces that are the plate and non of the deeper faces that are inside the letters then color those faces. I'm sure someone has a much better idea than myself.

Thank you for any help you can provide!

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you want something quick and dirty, you could create a mask based on the axis co-ordinates of the faces of your "lettering" (I used X axis in my example). An unfortunate side effect, however, is that it leaves a black stripe around the edge of the object at the same X-position:

[image: EmbossColor]

If instead, you want to select the letter faces and assign them a different material (ie: you just need a quick way to select all the faces at a certain "depth"), select one of the faces at that depth and then `select > similar > co-planar`. You can then assign a different material to the selected faces:

[image: CoplanSelect]

Comment: Thank you! I ended up doing something much less sophisticated and selecting the faces from top down view in wire mode. It worked for the timeline I had. Thank you for your help, I'll definitely use your technique in the future!